# Extend a basis of S to a basis for V.

Tags: vector-spaces

[image]

I have done the first part, how to proceed for the second part.

[image]

I know we need to add two independent vectors to B to make it a basis of V. But how to choose those two vectors?

Comment: Reason for negative voting?

Comment: Please use MathJax

Comment: While typing your posts is preferable, I think that this one is fine in its current form. Matrices are somewhat cumbersome to code into MathJax, the handwriting is very readable and the picture has a decent quality.

Comment: There are many ways to extend a linearly independent set (which is not a basis) to a basis.  One approach would be by comparing the span of the given linearly independent set to the whole vector space, and adding the minimal number of additional vectors so that the set spans the whole vector space.

Answer (score 2):

You did well to use the equations $a + b + c= 0$ and $a+d+g=0$
to eliminate the variables $c$ and $g$ from the matrix.
But the conditions are that the sum of *each* row is zero, and
the sum of *each* column is zero.
You have two more rows and two more columns,
giving you another four equations to be satisfied.

In the end, as it happens,
it will turn out that one of those equations is redundant,
but I think working them all out will allow you to write basis vectors
that are actually members of $S$.
The number of basis vectors will be fewer than shown in your first attempt.

Answer (score 0):

None of your matrices $A_1,\ldots,A_7$ is an element of $S$. So, how can $\{A_1,\ldots,A_7\}$ be a basis of $S$? Note furthermore that the sum in **each** column and row has to be zero.

Comment: Oh yeah, I didn't read the question properly. I thought they are saying that sum of entries of first row and first column is zero.